# PropertyVetoException in Java

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, exception

I am reading the oracle docs for java 7. I want to know what is `PropertyVetoException` in java. Can anyone please explain in details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a really old concept of the JavaBeans specification.

You can have **constraint properties** which will only change if the constraint is met. And this can be implemented with the *VetoableChangeSupport*.

It just works likes the *PropertyChangeSupport* but throws the Exception you are asking for when a VetoListener says the constraint is not met don't change!

See here for a little example: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/writing/properties.html